# 'mount -t ntfs-3g' Fails (exit code 1) but 'ntfs-3g' Succeeds

Tags: 12.04, mount, filesystem, ntfs

I'm currently on 12.04LTS and I've installed a couple of updates. (not sure which)

Now my nautilus cannot mount any NTFS partition (complaining about exit code 1), and indeed

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda3 /media/DATA; echo $?
```

prints 1. (`/dev/sda3` is an NTFS partition).
But stranger still, by invoking `ntfs-3g /dev/sda3 /media/DATA` I could get it mounted and then used normally (in either case, of course, I create `/media/DATA` manually).

`man ntfs-3g` tells me these two should be kind of aliases so I'm not sure why.

**what I've tried**

- Installing whatever updates available. (Nope, it doesn't work. Probably because the system's `/etc` has once been recovered from an older backup)
- `ntfs-config`. No it doesn't work. It adds entries to `/etc/fstab` but then I've been forced to skip mounting it when booting.
- `dpkg-reconfigure ntfs-3g`. I tried all 4 combinations (YY,NY,YN, NN) for the two questions available during the procedure and I rebooted my PC each time I experimented. Not work.

Yeah, I could've set up a startup script to use `ntfs-3g` to mount my drives.

My `strace` for `mount -t ntfs-3g`

```
execve("/bin/mount", ["mount", "-t", "ntfs-3g", "/dev/sda5", "/media/DATA"], [/* 27 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x96f5000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb779c000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=141237, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 141237, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb7779000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0P8\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=162044, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 164784, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb7750000
mmap2(0xb7776000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25) = 0xb7776000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0`C\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=157544, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 160260, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb7728000
mmap2(0xb774e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25) = 0xb774e000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0@A\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=120748, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7727000
mmap2(NULL, 125852, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb7708000
mmap2(0xb7725000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c) = 0xb7725000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0000\226\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1730024, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1743580, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb755e000
mprotect(0xb7701000, 4096, PROT_NONE)   = 0
mmap2(0xb7702000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1a3) = 0xb7702000
mmap2(0xb7705000, 10972, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7705000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\260\17\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=18012, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 20700, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb7558000
mmap2(0xb755c000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3) = 0xb755c000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0`\n\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=13940, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 16504, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb7553000
mmap2(0xb7556000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2) = 0xb7556000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7552000
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7551000
set_thread_area({entry_number:-1 -> 6, base_addr:0xb7551780, limit:1048575, seg_32bit:1, contents:0, read_exec_only:0, limit_in_pages:1, seg_not_present:0, useable:1}) = 0
mprotect(0xb7702000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb7556000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb755c000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb7725000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb7776000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb774e000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x805d000, 4096, PROT_READ)    = 0
mprotect(0xb77bf000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0xb7779000, 141237)              = 0
statfs64("/selinux", 84, {f_type="EXT2_SUPER_MAGIC", f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=7211656, f_bfree=3093320, f_bavail=2731836, f_files=1810432, f_ffree=1623318, f_fsid={85910847, -1799323758}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x96f5000
brk(0x9716000)                          = 0x9716000
open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb779b000
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\trootfs\nnodev\tb"..., 1024) = 322
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xb779b000, 4096)                = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=10411536, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 2097152, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb7351000
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0x434) = 0xb779a000
mmap2(NULL, 1716224, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0x714) = 0xb71ae000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=10411536, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0x2a1) = 0xb71ad000
mmap2(NULL, 1503232, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0x5a5) = 0xb703e000
close(3)                                = 0
umask(022)                              = 022
open("/dev/null", O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)   = 3
close(3)                                = 0
getuid32()                              = 0
geteuid32()                             = 0
readlink("/dev", 0xbfe5a51b, 4096)      = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
readlink("/dev/sda5", 0xbfe5a51b, 4096) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
stat64("/sbin/mount.ntfs-3g", {st_mode=S_IFREG, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0xb75517e8) = 4487
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 1}], 0, NULL) = 4487
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
exit_group(1) = ?
```

Comment: Try to run the `mount -t ntfs-3g` command and look at the output of `dmesg` for possible error messages that don't appear on stderr. Try the same with `mount -t ntfs` for comparison (this is what I'm using).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not fix the problem *technically*, but anyway I *symlink*ed `/bin/ntfs-3g` to `/sbin/mount.ntfs-3g` and it looks as though it works. (But still, another nasty fix.)